# Calculating and adding percentages in python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, math, percentage

i have a pandas series as follows:

```
0     211936162.0
1     133155855.0
2     131922983.0
3     228274558.0
4      77817617.0
5      80240498.0
6     163410293.0
7     152525334.0
8     355737880.0
9     160996360.0
10    261306387.0
11     68072101.0
12    131858324.0
13    276186629.0
14    219055004.0
15    133351461.0
16    240856457.0
17    239126380.0
18    123444603.0
19    178451251.0
20    323185205.0
21    167640620.0
22    225216720.0
23    446316998.0
24    436394155.0
```

these numbers represent income. I need to add the TVA of the country to this income which is at 19% of the price. To do this my guess was to create a function that do the job, and later use the `.apply` method to get this applied to the whole series.

I have to calculate the 19% of each element in the series and later add their respective 19% value to each of the original numbers in the series to get the TVA applied.

i was building a function like this one but i got a bit lost and cant figure out how to make it work:

```
def tva(series):
    for i in series:
        percentage = pd.Series((19 * i)/100)
        series[i] = percentage + series[i]
```

This function throws an error:

```
TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable
```

i will highly appreciate if someone could help me with this one.

Thanks in advance

Comment: do you really need a function for that: `ser_name *= 1.19` ? ;-)

Comment: thank you for your answer, i'm quite new to python, sorry for my ignorance, but i thought a function was the way to go. why 1.19?? and not 0.19??

Comment: if you want to add 19% to the value `100`, you just multiply it by `1.19`, so you'll have `119` as a result, does it sound reasonable for you?

Comment: you can try series.iteritems, example:

for i in series.iteritems:
     percentage = ((19 * i)/100)
     series[i] = percentage + series[i]

Comment: thanks a lot @ShrinivasDeshmukh it works just fine!! is good to know another way of doing this :)

Comment: glad to know :)